# Vista Run Dialogue: This task will be created with administrator priviledges

Tags: windows-vista, uac, runas

At work, I use Standard Server 2008, and the run dialogue there has a note that says "This task will be created with administrator priviledges" as per subject. At home, on this laptop with Vista Home Premium, there's no such text, and I'm getting a bit tired of firing up various utilities and not having them work.

Googling a bit notes that there was supposed to be some shortcut (ctrl+shift+enter), to launch programs as administrator, but that doesn't seem to work anymore. Maybe it was a beta thing?

runas /user:myself, doesn't seem to work, attempting to use handle.exe (sysinternals) still lets me know that I'm not an administrator (I'm the only user, and setup as Admin).

So what gives? What's an easy way to be able to run stuff as administrator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl+Shift+Enter is meant for the Windows Search box... works every time for me. Doesn't work from the Run box.

[image]

Comment: Ah, was not aware of that. I guess that's a good reason for using the net startmenu. Thanks for the pointer there!

Comment: I should also mention that you can simply go into the shortcut / application properties and choose to always run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that UAC is enabled and you haven't changed its settings, I suggest you not to turn it off just for the prompts to go away as it will cause you more harm than good. (There is more part of UAC than just the prompts, disabling that will cause permission problems when you don't suspect them. Example given: Settings of your games that are lost due to turning UAC of.)
2. Is your user member of the administrator group? If not, then you might want to try Safe Mode (sometimes does list an administrator account) or use some external tool to grant that account administrator rights.
3. Another thing you could try is to create a new account and see if the problems still occur there, if not, you might want to consider to transfer all your settings between both accounts.

How to perform that shortcut: Type something in start, eg. cmd, then you can press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to run the selected thing as administrator.

Thank you for that shortcut, I forgot about it, it comes out handy in some of my daily administration routines. (Easier to press than opening a right click menu and pressing a)

Answer (score 0):

> run dialogue there has a note that
>   says "This task will be created with
>   administrator priviledges" as per
>   subject

One common case when you can see this note: it is there when your UAC is disabled. Perhaps your computer in the office has it disabled?

The easiest and most common way how people who frequently need to run tasks as admins do is to disable UAC. Before you do this, be sure you understand the risks. (Without UAC you need to be more responsible and careful about what you do)